# Show that the chain rule gives $\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{∂z}{∂x} + \frac{∂z}{∂y} \frac{dy}{dx} $

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Show that the chain rule gives $$\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{∂z}{∂x} + \frac{∂z}{∂y} \frac{dy}{dx} $$ if we are given $z = z(x,y)$ and $y = y(x)$.

So the book says that when differentiating the function of a function chain rule shows that

$${dz}=\frac{∂z}{∂x}dx + \frac{∂z}{∂y}{dy}$$

What happens to the $dx$ though in this problem?

Here's my attempt, so $z$ is being differentiated in terms of $x$ and $y$ is a  function of $x$ $(y=y(x))$

So the partials are in both equations, the difference is the in the differentiation of $x$ and $y(x)$

The derivative of $y(x)$ is $\frac{d}{dx}y(x)$ which equals $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Now the derivative of x function is in terms of x, so it becomes $\frac{d}{dx}x$ which is equal to $\frac{dx}{dx}=1$, hence disappearing, just like the equation I need to show.

Comment: Regularly, the chain rule is *not* that thing.

Comment: The chain rule is $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}*\frac{du}{dx}$ where $u$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: Yes you are right, I meant the chain rule shows this when differentiating a function of a function

Comment: The problem in the title is different from that in the body?

Comment: The problem is saying with the conditions of z and y, that the equation in the description changes to the one in the title

Comment: Chain rule gives $${dz \over dx} = \left({\partial z \over \partial x}\right) {dx \over dx} +  \left({\partial z \over \partial y}\right) {dy \over dx}$$.